# Draw a line between two objects

Tags: swift, cocoa, drawing

I try to write simple app to draw vertexes and edges between them. I successfully wrote code to add vertexes, delete them and drag around the view. But when I tried to draw a line between them I came across problems. A lot of guide about this are outdated with old versions of Swift or about IOS development so I didn't find how to implement this.

I tried just to draw a line between to points, but nothing worked, also noticed that I want to change coordinates of edge when I drag the vertex.

```
import Cocoa

var merging = false
var mergingCoords:[CGPoint] = []

class Vertex {
    var number:Int

    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }

}

class Graph {
    var size = 0
}

class VertexView: NSBox {

    var point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)!
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if (merging) {
            print("Really")
            mergingCoords.append(self.point)
            if (mergingCoords.count == 2) {
                // DRAW AN EDGE
            }
        } else {
            point = event.locationInWindow
        }
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if (!merging) {
            if (event.locationInWindow == point) {
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            } else {
                point = event.locationInWindow
            }
        }
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        if (!merging) {
            self.frame = NSRect(x: event.locationInWindow.x - 20, y: event.locationInWindow.y - 20, width: 40, height: 40)
        }
    }

}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var graph: Graph = Graph()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print(event.characters!)
        if (event.characters! == "M") {
            merging = !merging;
            mergingCoords.removeAll()
        }
        print(merging)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let v = VertexView(frame: NSRect(x: event.locationInWindow.x - 20, y: event.locationInWindow.y - 20, width: 40, height: 40))
        v.boxType = NSBox.BoxType.custom
        v.point = event.locationInWindow
        v.cornerRadius = 20
        graph.size = graph.size + 1
        self.view.addSubview(v)
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? What does didn't work mean? Update your question with this information so people do not give you answers that you already tried. You should look at Apple's Quartz framework. It's designed for doing things like drawing lines.

Comment: There's lots of things that look wrong here. You say you want to do custom drawing but you have no `drawRect` method. That's how stuff gets drawn in Cocoa; you can't draw anything outside of `drawRect`. This is sort of Cocoa 101, so I'd suggest starting with the [Creating a Custom View](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html) guide.

Comment: Do you mean I have to create new view every time I want to draw a line? Or how?